# Update git pull url for submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have git with local readonly mirror (Atlassian Bitbucket Server).

I have repository with many submodules.

What i want to do is to update the fetch url in repo and all submodules  to `MIRROR_URL`.

For one repo it is easy -

```
git remote set-url        origin MIRROR_URL 
git remote set-url --push origin MASTER_URL
```

But when i call `git submodule sync` it makes `MIRROR_URL` as both fetch and push url for all submodules.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `git submodule sync`.

As you can see from the documentation of [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), the `sync` command

> Synchronizes submodules' remote URL configuration setting to the value specified in .gitmodules

and the [gitmodules doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules) shows that no `pushurl` option is available.

In your case you could set the pushurl of each submodule manually (or with a script), editing the config file under `.git/modules/your_module/config`

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
git submodule foreach <command>
```

In your case you can do a pull/update or any other command you want to execute.

Comment: And how do you deal with different submodule urls?

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because each submodule has different url